# Sorting content of arrays in controller

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller

I've got a 'status' and 'type' within a 'subjects' table. This status can contain the strings: 'Open', 'In progress' and 'Closed. I want to sort the output with 'In progress' first, then 'Open', then 'Closed'.

Within the sortings of status, I want to sort on types too, which can contain four different strings too.

Is this possible (in a controller) and if yes; how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by using `enum`.

I removed the string columns and used integers instead

```
schema.db

t.integer  "status",     default: 0
t.integer  "casetype",   default: 0
```

Then I added this to my Subject model

```
subject.rb

enum status: ['In progress', 'Open', 'Closed']
enum casetype: %w(Info NFI RFC RFA)
```

Then I ordered with this:

```
@subjects = Subject.all.order('status ASC, casetype')
```

More info about enum: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: You could use enum status as following `enum status: %w(In\ progress Open Closed)`